# Cambiar separador de decimal en Android

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy ejecutando lo siguiente en mi aplicación android: `LocaleData data = LocaleData.get(desiredLocale);` para obtener el separador de decimales.

Actualmente la variable `desiredLocale = 'es'` y me devuelve el separador de decimal como "," - Como puedo hacer para obtener el separador de decimal "."

```
LocaleData.get(desiredLocale) = LocaleData[NaN="NaN",amPm=[a. m., p. m.],currencyPattern="#,##0.00 ¤",currencySymbol="¤",decimalSeparator=',',eras=[a. C., d. C.],exponentSeparator="E",firstDayOfWeek=2,fullDateFormat="EEEE, d 'de' MMMM 'de' y",fullTimeFormat="H:mm:ss (zzzz)",groupingSeparator='.',infinity="∞",integerPattern="#,##0",internationalCurrencySymbol="XXX",longDateFormat="d 'de' MMMM 'de' y",longMonthNames=[enero, febrero, marzo, abril, mayo, junio, julio, agosto, septiembre, octubre, noviembre, diciembre],longStandAloneMonthNames=[enero, febrero, marzo, abril, mayo, junio, julio, agosto, septiembre, octubre, noviembre, diciembre],longStandAloneWeekdayNames=[, domingo, lunes, martes, miércoles, jueves, viernes, sábado],longTimeFormat="H:mm:ss z",longWeekdayNames=[, domingo, lunes, martes, miércoles, jueves, viernes, sábado],mediumDateFormat="d MMM y",mediumTimeFormat="H:mm:ss",minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,minusSign="-",monetarySeparator=',',narrowAm="a. m.",narrowPm="p. m.",numberPattern="#,##0.###",patternSeparator=';',perMill="‰",percent="%",percentPattern="#,##0 %",shortDateFormat="d/M/yy",shortMonthNames=[ene., feb., mar., abr., may., jun., jul., ago., sept., oct., nov., dic.],shortStandAloneMonthNames=[ene., feb., mar., abr., may., jun., jul., ago., sept., oct., nov., dic.],shortStandAloneWeekdayNames=[, dom., lun., mar., mié., jue., vie., sáb.],shortTimeFormat="H:mm",shortWeekdayNames=[, dom., lun., mar., mié., jue., vie., sáb.],timeFormat_Hm="H:mm",timeFormat_Hms="H:mm:ss",timeFormat_hm="h:mm a",timeFormat_hms="h:mm:ss a",tinyMonthNames=[E, F, M, A, M, J, J, A, S, O, N, D],tinyStandAloneMonthNames=[E, F, M, A, M, J, J, A, S, O, N, D],tinyStandAloneWeekdayNames=[, D, L, M, X, J, V, S],tinyWeekdayNames=[, D, L, M, X, J, V, S],today="Hoy",tomorrow="Mañana",yesterday="Ayer",zeroDigit='0']
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer algo muy simple, al final donde lo muestras es un String, entonces lo que puedes hacer es remplazar la "," por un "." así:

`String valor = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(12345.6); valor.replace(",",".");`